# resolving scope of private method call within a function in another private method for typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Framework: **Angular 5.x**

Structure is as follows:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   // ... Some svg rendering code
   function dblclick(d) {
       d3.select(this).select('circle').transition()
         .duration(1000)
         .attr('r', 14);

       this.makeJsonBackEnd(d); // in the browser console this is not a function error
   }
}

makeJsonBackEnd(node) {
 // extract info from d3 node to make a JSON for backend
}
```

I think because of the `function` within the `ngAfterViewInit()` the scope of the Component class is messed up and `this` is not recognized.

How can I call `makeJsonBackEnd()` within the `dblclick()`?

I tried making `dblclick` a private method for the class but the `this` call within `d3.select(this)` won't get recognized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a closure.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   const self = this;
   // ... Some svg rendering code
   function dblclick(d) {
       d3.select(this).select('circle').transition()
         .duration(1000)
         .attr('r', 14);

       self.makeJsonBackEnd(d); // in the browser console this is not a function error
   }
}

makeJsonBackEnd(node) {
 // extract info from d3 node to make a JSON for backend
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try turning dblclick method into Arrow function like below

```
dblclick = d => { .... };
```

or the traditional way of holding this scope into local var. `let me = this`, and call the method with `me.makeJsonBackEnd(d)` like below

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    let me = this;
    function dblclick(d) {
        ...
        me.makeJsonBackEnd(d)
        ...
    }
 }
```

Comment: won't the `this` in `d3.select(this)` cause a problem in fat-arrow?

Comment: Yes it will, hence the closure.

Comment: Yes it affects, then use traditional way of solution, which would work for you.